# what is the "markdown" way to add newline in `$$`block in .rmd?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

Currently, I use

```
\begin{align*}
H_0: \beta_{religion} &\leq 0.2 \\
H_A: \beta_{religion} &> 0.2
\end{align*}
```

to produce

[image: newline]

but I want to do it by simply

```
$$
H_0: \beta_{religion} \leq 0.2 \\
H_A: \beta_{religion} > 0.2
$$
```

but it will produce the following:

[image]

Is there any way not to use any latex syntax but still achieve the same output?

here is the `.rmd` example:

```
---
title: example
output: pdf_document
---

\begin{align*}
H_0: \beta_{religion} &\leq 0.2 \\
H_A: \beta_{religion} &> 0.2
\end{align*}

$$
H_0: \beta_{religion} \leq 0.2 \\
H_A: \beta_{religion} > 0.2
$$
```

Thank you.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21126776/multi-line-equation-in-rmarkdown

Comment: Does this answer your question? [multi-line equation in RMarkdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21126776/multi-line-equation-in-rmarkdown)

Comment: @JessicaBurnett Thank you for your suggestion. But I do not think it answer my question. I know how to achieve what I what but I want to do it in a markdown way, I am expecting an answer that allows me to use markdown `$$` block and `\\\` to open newline instead of using any latex syntax.

Comment: unrelated to your question, but please don't set multiletter words like "religion" in math mode, the kerning is just horrible. Try with `\text{religion}`

Comment: I'm not sure there's going to be a multi-line solution without calling latex here. [@yihuixie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/559676/yihui-xie) provided the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47913433/multiline-latex-equation-in-r-markdown-and-windows), which suggests using {align}{/align} might be the best solution here.

Answer (score 1):

`$$ H_0: \beta_{religion} \leq 0.2 $$`

`$$ H_A: \beta_{religion} > 0.2 $$`

Comment: Seems like this really is still the best answer... It's unfortunate especially because the preview within rStudio will show the equation as if it should be broken into multiple lines, but renders in PDF as a single line.

I like to add a negative vspace so the separate equations aren't so far apart:

`$$ H_0: \beta_{religion} \leq 0.2 $$`

`\vspace{-.5cm}`

`$$ H_A: \beta_{religion} > 0.2 $$`